# What is a document called, which records the process of a company giving its staff necessary items to their use for work?

Tags: business-language

Sorry for slaying the English in the title but I don't know how to be more explanatory.

For example John starts working with Microsoft as a programmer, and the company gives him a computer which is still company's property, but for the usage of John. What is that action called? Issuing? Commisioning? Deploying?

What would be the name of a document which records that action?

Comment: a 'Provisioning Ledger' could work.  'Provisioning' sounds like something you'd do in the military though and 'ledger' sounds really bureaucratic. "Equipment Log" or "Employee Equipment Log" might sound more friendly.  "each employee gets equipped with a company computer ?"

Comment: Hmm, "Provisioning Ledger" seems close. It should sound bureaucratic, as it will be used in a governmental resource management software. It is a document that lists items under the use of a specific employee.

Comment: We call the process 'onboarding' at our company. Not sure what the document would be called though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Issued** sounds right. **Assigned** is another good possibility.

I would call the document that records the action a **property record**. Many organizations keep track of computers and other assets issued to employees by assigning **property numbers** to such assets and by maintaining **property records** in **property databases**. Local organizational **property custodians** (or equivalent) reconcile such inventories on some required basis, e.g., annually. The individuals to whom property is **issued** or **assigned** are responsible for the property **issued** or **assigned** to them. It's all in the **property records**.

Comment: In our company, we can it an "asset register"